# Jenkins + Phing: Who should deploy and who should clone?

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration, phing

I have Jenkins setup to build and deploy my project using Phing.

Inside the Phing build.xml file, I create a set of targets for doing useful stuff, such as running tests, static code analyzer and such.

Phing also is responsible for deploying the application, creating a structure similar to this:

```
var/www
    current -> /var/www/develop/releases/20100512131539
    releases
        20100512131539
        20100509150741
        20100509145325
    features
    hotfixes
```

The thing is, Jenkins does a git clone of the project and Phing also does it, inside the releases directory. With this, I have two clones on the same build and deploy process.

My question is: the responsibility of cloning the repository should be of Phing or Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I leave Phing the same sort of tasks you mentioned: like static code analyzer, running tests, linters, etc.
The reason for this, is that as a dev, I might want to run all these test (or a set of them) regularly during my development, and Im able to trigger them on my local environment without the need of jenkins.

For deployment stuff, I leave jenkins in charge of it, so would leave jenkins to continue doing it.

But, if you want to have everything in phing, I think that would be ok, too. I would split the tasks to have a group of dev test to be run on console, and a jenkins tasks to be run on the deploy.

Definitively, only one of them should be doing so.